# Trying to split emdash (long dash) but dtm keeps replacing it as the short dash

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following:

```
var dates = document.querySelector('#txDates').textContent.split("—");
```

but every time I add this into Adobe DTM, it converts it to a - rather than the long dash —

How can I get it to do the — in that split? Because of the conversion to short dash, it's not running my script correctly. I need it to split that long dash as it's part of the text that's on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a workaround used in Adobe Captivate posted in the [adobe community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/captivate/em-dash/td-p/1762253?page=1) but I'm not sure if tagging works the same way in DTM.

Basically you need to create a user variable, copy the emdash symbol from somewhere and then in the field 'Value' in the 'Actions' dialogue. Save the variable, open the caption and type $$em-dash$$ on the right place.

Comment: thanks, i tried looking into something like this but was unlucky, unless i was doing it wrong but the functionality appears different in tagging (DTM) vs captivate. thank you